# Tickless Idle Mode not satisfying if( xModifiableIdleTime > 0 )

Tags: stm32, freertos, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to use FreeRTOS Tickless idle mode. When I am debugging my code (using breakpoints), I see that the code enters vPortSuppressTicksAndSleep function.

```
/* Sleep until something happens.  configPRE_SLEEP_PROCESSING() can
        set its parameter to 0 to indicate that its implementation contains
        its own wait for interrupt or wait for event instruction, and so wfi
        should not be executed again.  However, the original expected idle
        time variable must remain unmodified, so a copy is taken. */
        xModifiableIdleTime = xExpectedIdleTime;
        configPRE_SLEEP_PROCESSING( xModifiableIdleTime );
        if( xModifiableIdleTime > 0 )
        {
            __asm volatile( "dsb" ::: "memory" );
            __asm volatile( "wfi" );
            __asm volatile( "isb" );
        }
        configPOST_SLEEP_PROCESSING( xExpectedIdleTime );
```

I also see that xExpectedIdleTime has a valid value. But after configPRE_SLEEP_PROCESSING( xModifiableIdleTime ); xModifiableIdleTime becomes 0 and it doesn't enter if( xModifiableIdleTime > 0 ) condition. Also the comment above mentioning "configPRE_SLEEP_PROCESSING() can

set its parameter to 0 to indicate that its implementation contains

its own wait for interrupt or wait for event instruction, and so wfi

should not be executed again." is confusing me.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.  if `configPRE_SLEEP_PROCESSING` enters sleep itself then `if` should not be executed.

Comment: The system goes into the sleep mode with __asm volatile( "wfi" ); If I go inside configPRE_SLEEP_PROCESSING, we get 

`#define configPRE_SLEEP_PROCESSING(__x__)                           \
                                       do {                         \
                                         __x__ = 0;                 \
                                         PreSleepProcessing(__x__); \
                                      }while(0)`


And there is nothing inside PreSleepProcessing(__x__); This is used if I want to turn off specific clocks.

Comment: @NafiurRahman you you set it to zero you need to have your own one `wfi` or `wfe` in that macro/function. That is the logic. It does not contain it in that stub. So if you do not have it comment the `__x__ = 0;` line

Comment: I actually got it working, apparently in the library, it should be 
`#define configPRE_SLEEP_PROCESSING  PreSleepProcessing`

Comment: And I got what you mean as well! Thanks for the help.